# Does an onShow() function exist for Qt Applications?

Tags: c++, qt

My goal is to hide() a window1 and then show() another window2.

However, when I want to later hide window2, I want to resume window1 and for it to automatically call several functions to update itself.

**Does an onShow() function, or something similar, exist?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should derive from Your window class and use the [showEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/QWidget.html#showEvent) overload

Comment: This window1 is accessed from two windows: window2 and window3.        I only want this functionality when window2 show()s it, not window3. How can I do this?

Comment: Your window on this event can emit a signal with it's identificator and there can be a listener that will show propper window called StateManager or WindowManager.

Comment: @s_rc: Put the logic in window2, rather than window1. When window2 calls `window1->show()`, make it do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for a signal.

No, such a signal does not exists. You could create one by subclassing the window from QWidget and reimplementing the QWidget::showEvent() event handler where you could emit your custom signal.

For QDialog derived windows you could use the accepted()/rejected()/finished() signals.

You description however sounds a bit like a wizard. Have a look an QWizard, maybe it helps you.